# Set number of arguments programmatically

Tags: r, loops

I have the following string:

```
test <- "C:\\Users\\stefanj\\Documents\\Automation_Desk\\script.R"
```

I am separating the string on the backslash characters with the following code:

```
pdf_path_long <- unlist(strsplit(test, "\\\\", 
                       fixed = FALSE, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE))
```

**What I want to do is:**

```
pdf_path_short <- file.path(pdf_path_long[1], pdf_path_long[2], ...)
```

**Problem is:**

I know how to count the elements in the pdf_path_short - `length(pdf_path_long)`, but I don't know how to set them in the file.path as the number of elements will very based on the length of the path.

Comment: See `?do.call` and try `do.call(file.path,as.list(pdf_path_long))`

Comment: @nicola yes, thats it. You should post it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: is `gsub("\\", "/", test, fixed=TRUE)` what you want? (what is exactly the aim? R understands file paths with `\\`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly (no need for a `strsplit` call) use `gsub` on `test` to change the separators (with `fixed=TRUE` so you don't need to escape the double backslash), you will get same output as with `file.path`:

```
pdf_path_short <- gsub("\\", "/", test, fixed=TRUE)
pdf_path_short
# "C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/Automation_Desk/script.R"
```

Of course, you can change the replacement part with whatever separator you need.

---

**Note:** you can also check `normalizePath` function:

```
normalizePath(test, "/", mustWork=FALSE)
#[1] "C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/Automation_Desk/script.R"
```